# How to add a customer programmatically in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.0

I need to create a customer programmatically in Magento 2, I haven't found much documentation around... basically what I need to do is translate the following code into "Magento 2":

```
$websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
$store = Mage::app()->getStore();

$customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
$customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
            ->setStore($store)
            ->setFirstname('John')
            ->setLastname('Doe')
            ->setEmail('jd1@ex.com')
            ->setPassword('somepassword');

try{
    $customer->save();
}
```

Comment: you want to do this in a standalone script, or you have a model or something?

Comment: @Marius, I have been working on this module and I have created a controller. It this controller I need to prepare some data to be saved and the idea is to call the customer model and save that information. The code above can be placed in a controller I would like to do the same but for Magento 2. I am still a bit confused with the new structure of Magento 2 and stuck here now.. I know It has something to do with class injections and object instances but I am not sure how to do it...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Okay, after a while I found a solution in case someone else needs it.. 
Magento uses another approach to instantiate objects, the traditional way to instantiate objects in Magento 1.x was using "Mage::getModel(..)", this have changed in Magento 2. Now Magento uses an object manager to instantiate objets, I won't enter in details about how it works.. so, the equivalent code for creating customers in Magento 2 would look like this:

```
<?php

namespace ModuleNamespace\Module_Name\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory
     */
    protected $customerFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context      $context
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory    $customerFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager     = $storeManager;
        $this->customerFactory  = $customerFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        // Get Website ID
        $websiteId  = $this->storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

        // Instantiate object (this is the most important part)
        $customer   = $this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

        // Preparing data for new customer
        $customer->setEmail("email@domain.com"); 
        $customer->setFirstname("First Name");
        $customer->setLastname("Last name");
        $customer->setPassword("password");

        // Save data
        $customer->save();
        $customer->sendNewAccountEmail();
    }
}
```

Hope this snippet of code help someone else..

Comment: You were very close. You should avoid using objectManager directly whenever possible--it's bad form. The proper way to do that is using dependency injection to get the 'factory' class, and use that to create an instance. If a factory class doesn't exist for a given class, it'll be auto-generated. I've edited your code to use this (added the factory to the constructor and class, and calling create()), and follow the PSR-2 code standards.

Comment: Thanks for the correction @RyanH. I thought about using factory classes but wasn't sure how to, so I used objectManager... I will read more about PSR-2 code standards for future projects. I am using the code with your corrections now and everything work perfectly.  Thanks

Comment: @RyanH. Done ; )

Comment: I can see it in databases but not for Admin panel. What happening?

Comment: @Arni; my first guess is that you'd need to reindex :)

Comment: I can save the default attributes by using above solutions, but how to save the custom attributes?

Comment: Have you tried something like this: $customer->setData("custom_attr", value);  @VenuJoginpally?

Comment: @Eduardo, Yes, I did it, but no use.

Comment: i follow the above code and the customer creation is succesfull but the customer is not able to login ..can any help me to solve this?

Comment: How to add address details?

Comment: why do we need to use the storeManager Dependency to create a user ?

Answer (score 7):

All the above examples will work, but according to the coding standards you should always **use service contracts** than the concrete classes.

Hence, the following way should be preferred for creating customer account programmatically.

```php
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class CustomerCreate
{
    public $store;

    public $customerFactory;

    public $customerRepository;

    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $store,
        CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerFactory,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->store = $store;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    }


    public function create()
    {
        try {
           /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface $customer */
           $customer = $this->customerFactory->create();
           $customer->setStoreId($this->store->getStoreId());
           $customer->setWebsiteId($this->store->getWebsiteId());
           $customer->setEmail($email);
           $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
           $customer->setLastname($lastName);

           /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository*/
           $customer = $this->customerRepository->save($customer);
           // Note: The save returns the saved customer object, else throws an exception.
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
          // Add log
       }
    }

}
```

Comment: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\CustomerRepository\Interceptor::save() must be an instance of Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface, instance of Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor given  I get this error running the above code

Comment: Hi, @BrandenB171 I have updated the complete code. It may be due to the use of customer model than customer API. Love an upvote if this works for you.

Comment: That was it. I was not using CustomerInterfaceFactory, rather CustomerFactory, and that was returning the resource model

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple way to create a new customer with default group and current store.

```
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerExtractor;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;

class CreateCustomer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var RequestFactory
     */
    protected $requestFactory;

    /**
     * @var CustomerExtractor
     */
    protected $customerExtractor;

    /**
     * @var AccountManagementInterface
     */
    protected $customerAccountManagement;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param RequestFactory $requestFactory
     * @param CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor
     * @param AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        RequestFactory $requestFactory,
        CustomerExtractor $customerExtractor,
        AccountManagementInterface $customerAccountManagement
    ) {
        $this->requestFactory = $requestFactory;
        $this->customerExtractor = $customerExtractor;
        $this->customerAccountManagement = $customerAccountManagement;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve sources
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $customerData = [
            'firstname' => 'First Name',
            'lastname' => 'Last Name',
            'email' => 'customer@email.com',
        ];

        $password = 'MyPass123'; //set null to auto-generate

        $request = $this->requestFactory->create();
        $request->setParams($customerData);

        try {
            $customer = $this->customerExtractor->extract('customer_account_create', $request);
            $customer = $this->customerAccountManagement->createAccount($customer, $password);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            //exception logic
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is $request here?, can we add custom attributes also?

Comment: How to set custom attributes ?

Answer (score 0):

*This code run in external file or console file CLI Magento*

```
namespace Company\Module\Console;

use Braintree\Exception;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;


class ImportProducts extends Command
{

    public function magentoStart()
    {
        $startMagento = $this->bootstrap();
        $state = $startMagento['objectManager']->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
        $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
        return $startMagento['objectManager'];
    }

    protected function bootstrap()
    {
        require '/var/www/html/app/bootstrap.php';
        $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
        $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
        return array('bootstrap' => $bootstrap, 'objectManager' => $objectManager);
    }

    protected function createCustomers($item)
    {
        $objectManager      = $this->magentoStart();
        $storeManager       = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $customerFactory    = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');

        $websiteId  = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer   = $customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->setEmail("eu@mailinator.com");
        $customer->setFirstname("First Name");
        $customer->setLastname("Last name");
        $customer->setPassword("password");
        $customer->save();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this using modern Magento 2 interfaces is as follows. This will avoid deprecated function warnings:

```
    /**  @var CustomerInterfaceFactory $customerFactory */
    $customerFactory = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get("\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory");

    $customer = $customerFactory->create();
    $customer->setWebsiteId(\ElectricLabs\MagentoHelpers::getCurrentStoreId());

    $customer->setEmail($emailAddress);
    $customer->setFirstname($firstName);
    $customer->setLastname($lastName);

    /**  @var CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository */
    $customerRepository = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get("\Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface");

    /**  @var Encryptor $encryptor */
    $encryptor = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get("\Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor");
    $passwordHash = $encryptor->getHash($password, true);
    $customer = $customerRepository->save($customer, $passwordHash);


    /**  @var SessionFactory $customerSessionFactory */
    $customerSessionFactory = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory');
    $session = $customerSessionFactory->create();
    $session->setCustomerDataAsLoggedIn($customer);

    /**  @var EmailNotification $emailNotification */
    $emailNotification = $this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get("\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification");
    $emailNotification->newAccount($customer);
```

Comment: `$this->_bootstrap->getObjectManager()` is not good way to work with Magento ;)