# custom form save and create customer in magento

Tags: customer, customer-account

Create a custom form for the registration(or creating customer account)  of customers is it possible?

Advance Thanks for help.

> app/code/local/Namespace/Customform/IndexController.php

```
public function saveAction()
{

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

    $firstname = $data['firstname'];
    $lastname = $data['lastname'];
    $company = $data['companyname'];
    $address1 = $data['address1'];
    $address2 = $data['address2'];
    $city = $data['city'];
    $state = $data['state'];
    $zipcode = $data['zipcode'];
    $phone = $data['phone'];
    $email = $data['email'];
    $pass = $data['password'];

    $websiteId = Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore();

    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer   ->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                ->setStore($store)
                ->setFirstname($firstname)
                ->setLastname($lastname)
                ->setEmail($email)
                ->setPassword($pass);

    $customer->save();

    $address = Mage::getModel("customer/address");
    $address->setCustomerId($customer->getId())
            ->setFirstname($firstname)
            ->setLastname($lastname)
            ->setPostcode($zipcode)
            ->setCity($city)
            ->setTelephone($phone)
            ->setCompany($company)
            ->setState($state);


    $address->save();



}
```

how to use cURL functions for the same use in customer save and customer address

Comment: Do you want to create custom form from which customer can be registered?

Comment: i have custom form so custom form submit customer craete

Comment: Okay do one thing In customer form submit you can get all data which is filled in form by using that data you can create customer programmatically  for that you can refer this answer it will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/78164/how-to-add-a-customer-programmatically-in-magento-2

Comment: Use same field names as magento use, also put form key to your form and submit it to createPostAction(which is magento's default register action).

Comment: now i accountcontoller ovveride and use createPost Action